# Sublime Text 3 Build System for Ubuntu

Tags: c++, compilation, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I want to compile and run C++ programs in Sublime Text 3. A few months ago I came across a build system that compiled and ran the program in terminal in a single command. Due to some reasons I no longer have the build system.

This is what I have in place:

```
{
  "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
  "variants":
  [
      {
          "name": "Run",
          "shell": true,
          "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name};echo;echo;  echo Press enter to continue....; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]
      }
  ]    
}
```

It works fine but I have to compile and run the program separately. Is it possible to modify this to achieve what I've mentioned above? Or maybe another build system that could do this?

Comment: The built in `C++ Single File` build system compiles and builds in a single step.

Comment: Yes, but it does not support inputs and does not launch the terminal. The build system I've specified does so but has variants. I want it to do compilation and running both in a single step in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the `shell_cmd` in that build, you can see how it uses `&&` to chain the compile and execution together into a single command. You can update your build to use `shell_cmd` instead of `cmd` to do the same thing along with using `gnome-terminal` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's irrelevant, I tried using sublime to compile c++ but couldn't. Then tried switching to atom and have been using it since. It can compile code from the editor. You can give it a try.